# string.charCodeAt(n)で、文章変換は、できない？

Tags: javascript, 文字コード

文字コードの変換で、`string.charCodeAt(n)`がありますが、文章ごと変換することは、できないのでしょうか？

むりやり、

```
var str1 = str.charCodeAt(0);
var str2 = str.charCodeAt(1);
document.form.value = str1 + ',' + str2;
```

と2文字しか変換できません。100文字近くの文章の文字すべてをJavaScriptで変換してTextArea内に表示させたいです。

お分かりの方、いらっしゃいますでしょうか、よろしくお願いします。

**例:**

"ABC": `97,98,99`

"": `55399,55399,55399,55399,55399`

Comment: [String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)は指定した1文字のUTF-16コードを取得するメソッドです。まずは質問者さんの考える「文字コードの変換」がどのような処理を求めているのかを説明してください。

Comment: 文字コードの変換なのが、文章変換なのか、正しい言葉を選ばないと正しい回答が得られません。

Comment: 質問が、言葉足らずで、わかりずらかったです、すいません、１００文字近くの文章の文字をすべて文字コード変換したいのです。

Comment: あなたの言う「文字コード変換」は、通常プログラマーが「文字コード変換」と言うのとは違う意味で使っているように思われます。どう言った入力に対して、どう言った出力を得たいのかを質問文中に追記すればわかりやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: 例えば`"ABC"`という文字列はどのような結果に変換されますか？またサロゲートペアを持つ`""`はどのような結果に変換されますか？区切り文字は？(`0xD8670xDE3D`, `55399,56893`, `171581`, etc.)
というように質問が全く具体的ではありませんので、質問文を編集して具体例を追記してください。

Comment: プログラマの素人で、質問内容が具体的でなく、ご迷惑おかけしています。質問の仕方だけでも教えていただきありがとうございます。

Comment: `"ABC"`の文字コードであれば`"65,66,67"`となるべきですが、そうではなく`"97,98,99"`ということは小文字に変換するということでしょうか？ 質問文が不正確では答えようがありません。`""`は１字に見えますが[サロゲートペア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#.E3.82.B5.E3.83.AD.E3.82.B2.E3.83.BC.E3.83.88.E3.83.9A.E3.82.A2)と言って内部的には２文字で構成されています。そのような場合にはどう表現されることを望まれているのでしょうか？ `55399`だけですと１文字目だけで、２文字目は取り除くという意味でしょうか？

Comment: 結局、希望する回答をいただいただけでなく、質問すら最後まで訂正していただき、今回は本当に感謝いたします。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

質問者様にサロゲートペアの知識がないもの&大文字小文字誤記と判断して回答したします。
やりたいことは「入力された文字列をUTF-16のコードポイントに変換する」として
期待値は

```
a => 97
A => 65
あ => 12354(0x3042)
 => 55399,56893(0xD8670x‌​DE3D)
(がなぜ2文字になるのかは後述)
```

ただし、そもそも質問者様の記載している期待値の設定が誤っている可能性がありますので後述する文章をお読みいただきたく思います。

コードとしては以下の様にループで回すだけです。(一発で変換できるAPIありましたら他回答者様フォロー願います)

```js
function decodeString(){
  var src = document.getElementById('src').value;
  var dest = '';
  for(i=0; i < src.length; i++) {
    dest += src.charCodeAt(i) + ',';
  }
  document.getElementById('dest').value = dest;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="decodeString()">
<textarea id="src" onchange="decodeString()">あaA</textarea>
<textarea id="dest"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

※質問本題とはそれますが、「文字コード」について記載します。

「文字コード」という言葉は
「文字集合(UnicodeやJISxxxx等　サポートする文字の種類を番号付けしたもの)」
と
「符号化方式/エンコード方式(UTF-16やShift_JIS等　文字集合をプログラムで扱うために符号化したもの)」
と人によって混同して使っていることがあります。
(私見では)文字コードというとエンコード方式を指すことが多いと思います。

踏まえまして、回答者様方が質問が曖昧であるとご指摘されているのは
「shift_jisをutf-8に変換みたいなことをやりたいのか？」(恐らく一般的には「文字コード変換」というとこれを想起するかと思います)
また「文字コードを表示」と言っても
「ページのエンコードにしたがってバイト文字列を表示」したいのか(Shift_JISならShift_JISのコード)、
「特定のエンコード方式のコードポイントを表示したい」のか(charCodeAt()はUTF-16のコードを返します。(というかjsの内部コード))
あるいは文字集合のコードポイントを出したいのか
のあたりで回答者様方は回答に困られたのかと思います。
質問者様の記載された例は「UTF-16のコードポイントを表示」となっておりますが、それが期待値でよいのかご確認いただきたく思います。

さらに文字集合と符号化方式を混同することが多いのはUTF-16のコードポイントとUnicodeのコードポイントは「大体同じ」である点にあります。
「あ」はUnicodeコードポイントもUTF-16のコードポイントも0x3042です。

UTF-16は「2byteでも他の文字と被りがなく使える範囲の文字」に関してはUnicodeそのままのコードポイントを使いますが
「2byteで表現しようとしてしまうと他の文字と被ってしまう部分」はサロゲートペアという手法を使いエンコードされます。

「」はその「2byteで表現しようとしてしまうと他の文字と被ってしまう部分」で
Unicodeで定義される171581番目(0x29E3D)の文字です。
そのまま表現してしまおうとすると0x0002と0x9e3dという文字と被ってしまいますよね。
そこで代用符号位置という特殊ポイントに置き換え0xD8670xDE3Dと4byteコードに符号化されます(サロゲートペア)。

Comment: コード部分は既に回答記載いただいていたsayuriさんの物の方が良いかと思いますが、いろいろ書いてしまったので残しておきます。。。

Comment: 詳しく、ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りサロゲートペアと言う言葉を初め始めてみました、で、希望していたものでした、本当に感謝いたします。

Answer (score 5):

- `"ABC"`→`"65,66,67"`
- `""`→`"55399,56893,55399,56893,55399,56893,55399,56893,55399,56893"`

でよければ

```
str.split('').map(function(c){return c.charCodeAt(0)}).join();
```

の１行で実現できます。
小文字に変換する場合は全角文字も変換するかなど条件を明確にする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。どうしたら、そんなに簡単にコードが書けるのか尊敬しかありません。基本から勉強して見ます、本当にありがとうございました。